# Java: List<E> decorator implementation with notification

Tags: java, list, decorator, notifications

I need to implement List decorator class, which notify registered listeners in case of any change in list. I have subclassed `AbstractListDecorator` from [org.apache.commons.collections15](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/collections/collections-generic/4.01/collections-generic-4.01-javadoc.jar!/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections15/CollectionUtils.html) and override methods like `add()`, `addAll()`, `remove(int)`, `remove(E)` and so on with my notifying.

But there are some holes in -- for example when iterating through List by default `AbstractListDecorator.iterator()` and call `Iterator.remove()` method, either overridden methods `remove(int)` or `remove(E)` doesn't call.

Is there any standard and safety practice for decorating such things?

Thank you.

Comment: The foolproof way is to implement `List` directly yourself.

Comment: Never mind, there is `AbstractIteratorDecorator` for it. But still much work, some elegant solution wanted, please :)

Comment: OK, List from scratch. But I need decorate more existing implementation of List instead.

Comment: I mean implementing `List` ensures you catch all the methods (well, except `equals`, `toString` and `hashCode`). Then do the forwarding yourself to an existing `List` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the iterator() and listIterator() methods, and provide a decorated iterator that will notify your listeners whenever remove() is called.

Comment: Thank you. That is what are `AbstractIteratorDecorator` and `AbstractListIteratorDecorator` for.